# How to generate same type of graphs using the previously written commands for a few hundred similar data sets?

Tags: file, r, graph, command

I have a few hundred of data sets which are within one data file, I need to first of all take the subsets of each data set, and I've written commands to generate a graph and csv file. Then I want to generate the same type of graphs and csv files for the rest of the data sets. I wonder if there's a command in R which I could use?

To be more specific, I have written out the commands for a particular subset as the following, and then I need to do the same thing for the rest of the data subsets, the only thing I need to change is to modify the subset names, for example, change "seven" into "eight", "seventout" into "eightout", etc. Is there a command in R that would do this for me? (So I don't need to repeat myself modifying the names, copying and pasting the same things into R.) Thank you very much!

```
alldata <- read.csv(file="file.csv",header=T,sep=",")

seven<- subset(alldata, aserno==7, select=c(I,C,D))  # aserno==7, so I need to change 7 into different numbers included in the data file

sevenout <- subset(seven, I=="a" & D>0, select=c(I,C,D))

f <- function(sevenoutf) nrow(sevenoutf)

sevennumber <- ddply(sevenout,.(C), f)

colnames(sevennumber)[2] <- "N"

sevenout$N <- sevennumber$N [match(sevenout$C, sevennumber$C)]

sevenout=data.frame(sevenout,"time"=c(1:nrow(sevenout)))

plot(sevenout$time, sevenout$N, type="n")

lines(sevenout$time,sevenout$N)           # the result that I need

write.csv(sevenout, "sevenM.csv", row.names=FALSE)        # the result that I need
```

Comment: Please re write the code in your question on separate lines so it is clear what is going on, use 4 spaces so they are highlighted as code.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a for loop for something like this is you want to clearly see what you are doing and do all your iterations in one step. You could also read in a list of file names if they are in the same directory, and nothing else is in that directory. For example:

```
setwd("/my_docs/my_project_data/") # where all your data files are

my.files <- list.files()

setwd("/my_docs/my_project_graphs/") # somewhere to save your graphs

for(i in 1:length(my.files))
   {
   temp.dat <- read.csv(my.files[i])
   YOUR FUNCTION

   pdf(paste(Sys.Date(),"_",my.files[i],"_graph.pdf", sep="")) # naming the pdf that will be written out
   plot(temp.dat$number, temp.dat$td, main=my.files[i])
   dev.off()
   write.csv(temp.dat, paste(Sys.Date(),"_",my.files[i],"_new_data.pdf", sep=""), row.names=FALSE)
   }
```

Depending on how/where you want to save them you could send them to different directories in that paste command by changing the start, paste("../graphs/",Sys.... and paste("/../new_data/",Sys....

As for your function, I'm still a little unclear on what that's doing but hopefully you can fit that in from here.

Comment: Thank you very much! But I'm sorry that I just found out that the few hundreds of files are in error, and the new data file I got includes all the data, which means I need to take the subsets first. So I'm wondering how I can list out the subsets and complete the commands? Is it similar? I've edited my question, and included the new commands. Please help me, thank you:)

Answer (score 0):

Try writing a wrapper function that calls your sub functions internally. Then pass the function the variable names via a list using one of the apply() functions ( tapply, sapply etc...) as fits your needs

```
MyWrapperFunction <- function( infile) {

                      a <- read.csv(file = infile)
                      a1 <- subset(a, inout==2, select=c(A,C,D))
                      f.sum <- function(a1f) sum(a1f$D)
                      atd <- ddply(a1, .(a1$C), f.sum)
                      colnames(atd)[2] <- "td"

                      f.nrow <- function(a1f) nrow(a1f)
                      aC <- ddply(a1,.(a1$C), f.nrow)
                      colnames(aC)[2] <- "number"

                      a_A <- merge(atd, aC, by="a1$C")
                      myplot <- plot(a_A$number, a_A$td)  # the result I need
                      # save as your desired image file, png, pdf, etc...
                      # e.g. pdf( myplot, file = paste( infile, "_plot.pdf, sep = "") )

                      # the result I need
                     write.csv(a_A, 
                              file = paste( infile, "_output.csv, sep = ""),
                              row.names=FALSE) }
```

And borrowing some code from nzcoops:

```
setwd("/my_docs/my_project_data/") # where all your data files are

my.files <- list.files()

setwd("/my_docs/my_project_graphs/") # somewhere to save your graphs

apply( my.files, MyWrapperFunction)
```

Here's a way to get started on a generic function for your subsetting issue

```
anotherWrapperFunction <- function( data, subset.critera,...)
```

where ... is other things you want to pass to the function

```
data.subset <- subset( data, aserno == subset.critera, #etc...)

data.subset.subset <- subset( data.subset, #etc...)
```

By the way I'm not sure why you're doing this in two subset steps you can do this all in the same call via &

```
f <- function(sevenoutf) nrow(sevenoutf)
```

Also you don't need to have this as a function `f <- nrow(sevenoutf)` accomplishes the same thing

```
data.subset.subset.ddply <- ddply( data.subset.subset, #etc...)

colnames(data.subset.subset.ddply)[2] <- "N"
```

etc...,

now write out the plots and csv file as before

```
# save as your desired image file, png, pdf, etc...
# using the subset criteria in the file name so you can ID the plot
# e.g. pdf( myplot, file = paste( "subset", subset.critera, "_plot.pdf, sep = "") )
```

and do the same with write.csv as I showed you above

Good luck

Comment: Chris, can you expand this a bit more? I think writing a wrapper function is the way to go here and OP could probably use another push into the right direction.

Comment: Roman, I expanded a bit. Could probably pretty this up some, and I'm not sure that `apply()` is the right function to use in this case. But that should get the OP down the road some.

Comment: Hey Chris, thanks a lot for the help:) As I've edited my question, I've found out that there's error with the files, so now I've got only one data file which includes all the data, so I need to subset them. Can you help me with how to use one command to subset all the files at one time? or Can you tell me what to do while having all the data within one file (I've written out the commands for one subset in my question.) Thanks again!

Comment: OP, with your revisions your problem is now quite a bit easier. Just write a generic function using the new code in your question and send in the subsetting command via a variable to `subset()`

Comment: Thanks! Could you please expand your answer a little bit? For example, how would you write the generic function?? I'm not quite familiar with R... Also, the data subsets in the data file are not named in order, the names are like 7, and then jump to 103, then to 400, how do I list out the subset names? Again, I really appreciate your help!

Comment: See the new edits. I could write the entire function for you but I figured you'd learn more if I gave you the general syntax. Since you're new to R I'd recommend reading the start-up guide before posting on this Q again. Some things you're asking are pretty basic.

Comment: Chris, I appreciate your consideration of having me to learn more:) But now I'm in a bit struggle of writing out the subset criteria...I wonder if you could give me some suggestions on how to do that, also, it'd be great if you could refer me to some good R guides/tutorials. I did some research but wasn't able to find out guide for my questions...maybe I'm not looking at the right places?

Comment: You're now asking for something different from the original post. Please mark this answer accepted and ask a new question specific to your subsetting problem. There are plenty of links on the main R site for tutorials. I'd start there.